# Fade out when running removeChild() in ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I am creating a very rudimentary UI in Flex and Open Exhibits SDK, which I'm just starting to learn.

The UI has buttons and text. When I click a certain button, it removes everything from the screen using `removeChild()` (by detecting Mouse Up), and puts in new buttons and text.

This is not very pretty. I would like there to be a fade out animation when `removeChild()` is invoked. How do I do this?

If there is an alternative to `removeChild()` for this case, what would it be?

Comment: the moment you call removeChild(), the DisplayObject disappears. To accomplish a fade-out effect, you could tween the alpha of an object from n to 0 and on Completion call the removeChild. Look into [TweenLite](http://greensock.com/tweenlite)

Answer (score 2):

1) In your current Mouse Up event handler initiate some tweening effects (in your case you want to decrease alpha) instead of removing the children.

2) Add new event handler to process tweening completion. Remove your children there and add new (possibly with tweening as well).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you can listen to [removed or removedFromStage event](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#event:removedFromStage), then prevent event to happen, start effect on event.target which is to be removed, and when effect ends then remove child.